# How check properly, if a `double` or `long double` fits into a `long long`?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, type-conversion, numeric-limits

It seems quite simple at the first thought, but I couldn't find any good descriptions covering this case.

I have a method which returns a 64bit value. The value is internally calculated using `long double` values. At the end of the method I would like to check, if the `long double` is in the range of the `long long` value, and otherwise just assign the maximum `long long` value.

I use the following code, which only checks the positive range, because there are no negative results:

```
long long calculateSomething()
{
    long double calculatedValue = ...;

    long long result;
    if (calculatedValue > static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max())) {
        result = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
    } else {
        result = static_cast<long long>(std::floor(calculatedValue));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now I wonder, `long double` can equal to a `double`. Will the conversion `static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max())` always work correctly?

Or is there another better way to check the range?

Comment: How about something like `( (sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT) >= 64)`? (If it's the number of *bits* that's important)

Comment: @Biffen This would be a static test of the type, my question has an actual `long double` value which has to be checked to be in the range of a `long long`. The question is: Can I safely cast `static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max())`, or will this lead to conversion problems.

Comment: The conversion `static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max())` will produce a value of type `long double` that is nearest to `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()`. This is true regardless of whether `long double` is the same size as `double`. Does this qualify as "working correctly"? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Assuming 64-bit `long long`'s, the conversion itself is safe (i.e., no UB) but may lose precision. The direction of the rounding, however, is implementation-defined, so it's possible that the `>` comparison returns `false` but the actual value in `calculatedValue` is still outside the representable range of `long long`s.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, loss of precision is no problem, as long the value after conversion make sense. I feared you could end up with a different value or similar, what would happen if you would cast the value down to a 32bit int.

Comment: @T.C. So, you mean, there is the possibility that you would end up with some wrong values near the maximum value of the `long long`? Is there another safe way to make sure you keep the value in the bounds of the `long long`?

Comment: A 64-bit `double` has 53 bits of mantissa. It is physically unable to precisely represent all values of a 64-bit integer. Once the integer is greater than 2^53, converting it to `double` must necessarily lose low-order bits.

Comment: So, is there a safe way to check for the bounds before casting the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion between floating point and integral types are specified in §4.9 [conv.fpint] of the C++ standard:

> 1 A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional
>   part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value
>   cannot be represented in the destination type. [ *Note*: If the
>   destination type is `bool`, see 4.12. —*end note* ]
>
> 2 A prvalue of an integer type or of an unscoped enumeration type can
>   be converted to a prvalue of a floating point type. The result is
>   exact if possible. If the value being converted is in the range of
>   values that can be represented but the value cannot be represented
>   exactly, it is an implementation-defined choice of either the next
>   lower or higher representable value. [ *Note*: Loss of precision
>   occurs if the integral value cannot be represented exactly as a value
>   of the floating type. —*end note* ] If the value being converted is
>   outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is
>   undefined. If the source type is `bool`, the value `false` is
>   converted to zero and the value `true` is converted to one.

A typical `long long` is 64 bits, so `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()` is 2<sup>63</sup>-1. This is much smaller than the smallest possible value for `LDBL_MAX`, which is `1E+37`. Thus, we are safely within the representable range for a `long double`. However, if the `long double` is 64 bits, 2<sup>63</sup>-1 is highly unlikely to be exactly representable, and you run into trouble because the standard says that the result is "an implementation-defined choice of either the next lower or higher representable value". In other words, it can go either way, and there you have a problem.

If the compiler picked the next lower representable value for the conversion, then all is well. Even if `calculatedValue  == static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max())`, it's still in the representable range of `long long` and the conversion is well-defined.

If the compiler picked the next higher representable value for the conversion (and round-to-nearest, the typical rounding used, will likely go this way since 2<sup>63</sup> is exactly representable), and `calculatedValue  == static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max())`, then `calculatedValue` is actually outside the representable range of a `long long`, but in your code you still try to cast it to a `long long`. So, per the first paragraph above, you have undefined behavior. Ouch.

The simplest fix is to test for `calculatedValue >= static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max())` instead of `calculatedValue > static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max())`. In the unlikely event that the compiler rounds down, you'll miss one case. Another possible fix is to test for `calculatedValue >= static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() + 1ULL)`, taking advantage of the fact that 2<sup>n</sup> for reasonable `n`s are exactly representable in floating point.

Comment: Why `+ 1ULL`? Wouldn't this case an overflow? Not `- 1LL` instead?

Comment: @Flovdis It converts both to `unsigned long long`, so it won't overflow. The point is to get the next higher exactly representable value so that the conversion is exact.

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my code accordingly. I did extensive tests using Visual C++ (2012/11.0) with 32 and 64 bit code. With 32bit code, a `long double` equals a `double`. The maximum `long long` value is `9223372036854775807`, which is converted into `9223372036854775800.0`. XCode's LLVM compiler on the other hand, uses a 64bit floating point value in both, 32 and 64bit code for `long double`, which converts into `9223372036854775807.0` with full precision. Same with latest GCC and clang compiler.

Comment: @Flovdis So it rounds down on VC. Interesting. When I tested it on GCC/clang with `double` it rounds up.

Comment: From my experience, today you only have to check VC++ for trouble, because it's the only compiler (of VC++/GCC/clang/LLVM) which shows really strange behavior in certain places. I also noted, that VC++ (2012) has no `std::round` function, which is really strange.